# Odoo v12 Add more data to many2one field in recordData javascript

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, many-to-one

The **recordData** object in javascript has all the fields data. In '**account.invoice**' this is the object:

[image: Invoice Form]

[image: Invoice Javascript recordData]

The **Many2one** fields data:

[image: res.partner Many2one data]

The "**data**" only has "*display_name*" and "*id*", but i need "*vat*" field.

Is there a way to get more fields?

My first option is a **rpc** to get the **partner** data using the id (*this.recordData.partner_id.data.id*), i tried and it works.

```js
var def = this._rpc({
    model: 'res.partner',
    method: 'search_read',
    domain: [
        ['id', '=', this.recordData.partner_id.data.id]
    ],
}).then(function (result) {
    partner_data = result[0];
});
```

My second option is a related field, also works.

```py
partner_vat = fields.Char(related='partner_id.vat')
```

But i want to know if i can avoid this **rpc** call and avoid create a new **related** field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you call search_read, you can specify fields param in your _rpc call. For example:

```
var def = this._rpc({
    model: 'res.partner',
    method: 'search_read',
    domain: [
        ['id', '=', this.recordData.partner_id.data.id]
    ],
    fields: ['id', 'vat'],
}).then(function (result) {
    partner_data = result[0];
});
```